Не работает <bits/stdc++.h> в Windows 10
Не работает #include <bits/stdc++.h> в CLion 2020.1 Build #CL-201.6668.126, built on April 9, 2020
MinGW скачал, gcc в powershell работает, но библиотеки из хедера не подгружает и пишет ошибки на функции по типу gcd.

пишет следующие ошибки:
"E:\CLion 2020.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Lolka\Desktop\CLion\cmake-build-debug-mingw --target CLion -- -j 12
Scanning dependencies of target CLion
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CLion.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\Users\Lolka\Desktop\CLion\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Lolka\Desktop\CLion\main.cpp:55:13: error: 'gcd' was not declared in this scope
     cout << gcd(1, 2);
             ^~~
C:\Users\Lolka\Desktop\CLion\main.cpp:55:13: note: suggested alternative: 'gcvt'
     cout << gcd(1, 2);
             ^~~
             gcvt
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\CLion.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/CLion.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:77: CMakeFiles/CLion.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/CLion.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: CLion] Error 2

При том что хедер ручками в каталогах mingw я вижу.
cmakelists выглядит вот так:
project(CLion)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(CLion main.cpp)
# add_executable(CLion bits-stdc++.h)
add_executable(F ${SOURCE_FILES})


Стоит инклюдить заголовочные файлы стандартной библиотеки.

@user7860670 Спасибо, но я специально stdc++.h использую.

Стандарт не содержит упоминаний о таком заголовочном файле. Нет ни одной причины его использовать и надеятся, что он обязательно должен быть.

@user7860670 он есть в файлах mingw, до этого такой же сетап работал на другом пк, не понимаю почему вы пишите комментарий о том что это не надо использовать, вместо комментария о том как это починить.

А это не надо чинить, надо писать корректный код. "не понимаю почему вы пишите комментарий о том что это не надо использовать" - еще раз: этот файл не является стандартным или публичной частью какой-либо библиотеки. Использующий его код заведомо сломан. Лажу вроде #include <bits/stdc++.h> могут разве что на каких-нибудь сервисах по "соревновательному" решению задач посоветовать.

Я ее использую для алгоритмических задач и использую на mac, не понимаю смысла рассуждения, если я написал конкретную проблему, которую пытаюсь решить. Какой толк писать о сломан код или нет, если его хедер можно спокойно использовать.

Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? Спокойно использовать можно хедеры из стандартной библиотеки.

@user7860670 я не собираюсь делать 70 строчную пелену из инклудов в основной код.
Ситуация комичная складывается. Я вас спрашиваю по чем пирожки, вы мне отвечаете пирожки вредны для здоровья лучше купите эклеры.


Из-за стандарта С++14, отсутствует gcd(), заменой может послужить
#define gcd __gcd или просто использование __gcd() с двумя подчеркиваниями. В более старших версиях (начиная с 17) присутствует обычная gcd
Скорее всего после настройки ваши зависимости стандартов сбились. И на данный момент является затруднительном поиск причины того, почему стандарт 17 версии не поддерживается вашим mingw, с учетом, что mingw32-make.exe во всех версиях одинаковый.
В остальном всё, что входит в стандарт 14 и bits/stdc++.h будет корректно работать.

